# Fetch value by dynamic key from javascript object

Tags: javascript

I just want to fetch object values by dynamic key, I need this because of web service providing data in this form

```
var apiData = [{first_name:"ashwani"},{second_name:"raju"},{third_name:"ravi"}]
var naming=["first","second","third"]
for(i=0;i<apiData.length;i++){
    var symKey=naming[i] + "_name";  
    console.log(apiData[i].symKey)
}
```

But I am getting `undefined`, how can I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use brackets `[]` instead of . notation.

`.symkey` will look for a property called `symkey` in the object.

```js
var apiData = [{first_name:"ashwani"},{second_name:"raju"},{third_name:"ravi"}]
var naming=["first","second","third"]
for(i=0;i<apiData.length;i++){
    var symKey=naming[i] + "_name";  
    console.log(apiData[i][symKey])
}
```

Comment: How `[ ]` work in object ? I could not understand this ? any reference please ?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp